# What is the rear aluminum backing called on sliding doors?

Tags: doors

I’m going to attach a picture as it’s difficult to describe. But essentially, this piece came off the front end of the outside stationary door of the sliding glass.[image] [image]

[image]
[image]

I took a picture of the piece I’m talking about,
Then I took another picture showing where it came off of, and the final pic is of another sliding door with my finger pointing to the piece on the stationary door.

Maybe this part can’t be replaced, but I have no idea what it is called to begin googling. It appears to essentially interlock with the moving door so that when the moving door is in the close position it helps keep bugs and drafts out by interlocking.

If anyone knows I’d be pleased to learn it name :).

Comment: You're going to want to contact the manufacturer with the model number of the door.  It's possible they have replacement parts.  Otherwise you're in the market for a new door.

Comment: @jwh20 like a true idiot, I used my angle grinder to cut off enough of that bent out edge and left enough to let the moving door slide into place. Now it seals and no longer catches. I actually can’t seem to find a manufacturer marking anywhere. Any idea where on the sliders they usually put them? One day I’m sure I’ll want to replace the door, but for now the situation is handled lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stationary Panel Interlock Weatherstrip?

[image: Sliding door diagram with hand drawn red circle!]

Comment: Great find! I added the hand drawn red circle to improve findability. Plus that's guaranteed to get you more votes! :D:D:D

Comment: Giving this the answer. I ended up finding the same drawing. But as the comment from another user said, it seemed hopeless to find the same part without knowing the door manufacturer.